# comtype error on python 3.6.3

Tags: python, pywinauto

I developed automation soft on python 3.6.2 and used pywinauto module for that. I shared this soft with python 3.6.3 user. When tried to ran my app on 3.6.3 it crashed. The crash was on "from pywinauto.application import Application" line. It pointed on lack of some attributes in "comtype". I solved it simply by copy-paste all related files of "comtype" from my 3.6.2 to 3.6.3 version of user. Then it worked perfect. My question is: Is there any conventional way to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback?

Comment: Thanks. Solved conventionally by manual installation/update of "comtypes" modules.

Comment: Great. Please mark your own answer as accepted. Anyway the error traceback would be useful for future recommendations for other users. Thanks!

Comment: Trying to recover this issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved conventionally by manual installation/update of "comtypes" modules.